# Excel VBA - Loop to next available blank cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to write a small section of code to create a new worksheet and insert values from a table in a source worksheet starting at row 2, column 1 thru column 4. Once it reaches the end, I need it to loop to the next row and start over.

The issue I have is that the below code loops back to row 1 of the new worksheet and data is overridden. Is there a simple way to have my loop start on the first blank row down?

[image: Input Data]

[[image: Desired Output][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8okXS.jpg)

```
Sub SAX()

Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsData As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Long, c As Long

Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
wsData.Name = "Data"
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Header")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

r = 2
Do Until Len(Trim(wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value)) = 0
    For c = 1 To 4
        wsData.Cells(c * 1, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(r, c).Value
    Next c

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    r = r + 1
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Providing some screenshots of the input data and desired output might be helpful here...

Comment: @DavidZemens I have updated to add sample input data with the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is this, assuming (from screenshot) that you're working with a structured `ListObject` table:

```
Sub SAX()

Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsData As Excel.Worksheet
Dim i as Long
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim vals As Variant

With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsData = Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    Set wsSource = .Worksheets("Header")
End With
wsData.Name = "Data"

'## Get a handle on the Table object
Set tbl = wsSource.ListObjects(1) 'Modify if needed

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

i = 1  'which row we start putting data on wsData
'## Iterate each row of data in the Table
For Each rng In tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows
    '## Dump this row's values in to an array, and transpose it
    vals = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)
    '## Put the array's values in an appropriately sized range on the wsData sheet:
    wsData.Cells(i, 1).Resize(UBound(vals)).Value = vals
    '## Increment the destination row number:
    i = i + UBound(vals)
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Here we transpose the `rng.Value` so that we can drop it in a column. We store this in the `vals` array.  We then use the `vals` array to determine the size of the range where the values will be placed on "Data" sheet, and also use the size of the `vals` array to increment our `i` variable, which tells us where to put the *next* row's data.

Or, maybe even more simply:

```
For i = 1 to tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells.Count
    wsData.Cells(i, 1).Value = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i).Value
Next
```

This works because a range is indexed by row/column, so we begin counting cell #1 at the top/left, and then wrap to the second row and resume counting, for example, the "cell index" is in this example table:

[image]

This can easily be put into a single row or column, just by iterating over the `Cells.Count`!

Comment: Works great and explained perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...you actually need two Row values, one for data, one for output:

```
Sub SAX()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
Dim lDataRow As Long, lCol As Long, lOut as Long

Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
wsData.Name = "Data"
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Header")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
lDataRow = 2
lOut = 1
Do 
  For lCol = 1 To 4
    wsData.Cells(lOut, 1) = wsSource.Cells(lDataRow, lCol)
  Next lCol
  lDataRow = lDataRow + 1
  lOut = lOut + 1
Loop Until Len(Trim(wsSource.Cells(lDataRow, 1))) = 0

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to create an array and write all the data at one time.

```
Sub SAX()
    Dim Data, v
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Header")
        With .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            x = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(.Cells.Count / 4, 0)
            ReDim Data(1 To x, 1 To 4)
            x = 1
            For Each v In .Cells

                If y = 4 Then
                    x = x + 1
                    y = 1
                Else
                    y = y + 1
                End If
                Data(x, y) = v
            Next
        End With
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        .Name = "Data"
        .Range("A1:D1") = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
        .Range("A2:D2").Resize(UBound(Data, 1)).Value = Data
    End With

End Sub
```